# Laravel 5 No CSRF value

Tags: php, laravel-5, csrf, csrf-protection

I have a simple log in form with a csrf token field. When I submit I get a token mismatch. When I look at the value in the form the value of the token is blank

Both the login form and the authenticate are both in the web middleware group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']],function(){
    Route::get('/login',function(){
        return view('auth.login');
    });

    Route::post('/authenticate_user','Accounts\Accounts@authenticateUser');

    Route::get('/bar',function(){
        return csrf_token(); // works
    });
});
```

That bar route does display a token

```
//login.blade
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="authenticate_user" method="post">
            <label for="login_name">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="login_name" name="login_name" required="required">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="required">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <br>
            <button type="submit" id="Login" name="login" value="Log In" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Unfortunately the csrf field value is blank when I look at the source code

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="">
```

I did clear the laravel session and view storage. I restarted my browser and web server (XAMPP using PHP 7.0.2 on win 7).

I also tried:

```
<?php
$encrypter = app('Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter');
$encrypted_token = $encrypter->encrypt(csrf_token());
?>
<input id="token" type="hidden" value="{{$encrypted_token}}">
```

Got a value but it still mismatched

I am sure I am doing something stupid but I have no idea why I am not getting a token value and mismatch

Answer (score 0):

You problem is

```
 {{ csrf_field() }}
```

it should be

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Using {!! !!} it will render HTML code

**UPDATE**
From the Laravel docs:

**Displaying Unescaped Data**

By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```